# What is wrong with this argument that $(-2)^{1/4}=4^{1/8}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, exponentiation, fake-proofs

My prof started today's lecture by writing $$(-2)^\frac{1}{4} = (-2)^{(2*\frac{1}{8})} = ((-2)^{2})^{\frac{1}{8}} = 4^{\frac{1}{8}}$$ and asked us whether this was valid or not. However he didn't provide any answer and just continued on from there.

In my opinion this is not valid because $(-2)^\frac{1}{4}$ should be a complex number whereas $4^{\frac{1}{8}}$ is a real number.

So my question is which step here is invalid? My guess would be the 2nd equality, and I'm guessing that $a^{mn}=(a^m)^n$ does not hold in every case. But I'm not entirely sure what the issue is here. Do we need $a>0$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: What does $(-2)^{1/4}$ mean ?

Comment: @JCAA not true, the solutions will just be complex

Comment: @JCAA could you elaborate why you don't think so? Since ${(-2)^{\frac{1}{4}}}$ is usually defined as the solutions to the equation ${z^4=-2}$ which makes perfect sense

Comment: @JCAA again, definable. Take the limit of the principle values of ${(-2)^{e_n}}$, where ${e_n}$ is any rational sequence converging to $e$. I'm not sure how that's relevant anyway, since OP isn't asking about irrational powers. It's rational. Just ask Wolfram alpha - it actually gives you these answers

Comment: @JCAA Wolfram alpha disagrees

Comment: @JCAA an alternative way is to do ${(-2)^e = e^{\log\left((-2)^{e}\right)}}$ which becomes ${e^{e\log(-2)}}$ and use the principal log. I'm sure there are other ways to also define these expressions - but to say "it's undefinable" is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to define what you mean by expressions like ${(-2)^{\frac{1}{4}}}$. The usual way is to think of this "expression" as a set of solutions to the equation

$${z^4 = -2}$$

Likewise, by ${4^{\frac{1}{8}}}$ usually refers to the set of solutions for the equation

$${z^8 = 4}$$

In other words, ${4^{\frac{1}{8}}}$ isn't just a real number, and also will refer to some complex numbers that satisfy ${z^8 = 4}$.

If you go by this definition, you can see the second equation is actually just the first equation squared on both sides. If you square an equation on both sides like this - the new equation will contain solutions valid for both equations, but will also contain other dummy solutions that do not. In other words, solving ${z^8 = 4}$ will give solutions for both ${z^4 = -2}$ **and** ${z^4 = 2}$. Hence if you think of these expressions as sets, ${(-2)^{\frac{1}{4}}\neq 4^{\frac{1}{8}}}$, but ${(-2)^{\frac{1}{4}}\subset 4^{\frac{1}{8}}}$.

---

You have to be careful applying power rules to things involving non-integer powers pretty much. Hope that helps :)

Comment: This clears things up. Thank you!

Comment: @Yakes no problem!